# using Lucida Grande in windows

Tags: css, fonts

I want to use Lucida Grande in my website for windows.

How to do that ?
how can i embed it to my webpage ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "website for windows"? A web site that can be viewed only on Windows?

Comment: no, Lucida Grande only viewed in Mac, it doesnt work in windows. I want to work it on windows too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the font-stack I've used in the past:

`font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;`

Comment: It's worth noting that, while this stack is *certainly* correct in how the font-stack is composed, in reality most Windows users will not have Lucida Grande installed. So in this example, most Windows users will be seeing either Tahoma or Verdana.

Answer (score 17):

I'm just looking for the same thing and stumbled upon this article:

http://www.brownbatterystudios.com/sixthings/2007/03/14/lucida-hybrid-the-grande-alternative/

It basically suggests to use `Lucida Sans Unicode` for normal text and `Lucida Sans` for bold and italic text.

```
body {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode";
}
b, strong, i {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans";
}
```

the complete code example (including fallback fonts) from the linked site:

```
body {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

strong, em, b, i {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Please remember to include the code that is referenced in those links, they sometimes expire, like in this case :(

Comment: @dvidsilva the link still works for me. but even if not, I don't think it's necessary to provide code as it's rather simple  (I'll add it anyways now)

Comment: Here is the link saved: https://web.archive.org/web/20140401033959/http://www.brownbatterystudios.com/sixthings/2007/03/14/lucida-hybrid-the-grande-alternative/

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande";
    src: url(/resources/fonts/lucidagrande.ttf);
}
.ace {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande";
    font-size: 90%;
}
</style>
```

and you should adjust the url used in the `src:` line and the actual location on disk of the `.ttf` file (depends on multiple factors: your document root location, or if you use a separate server for static resources, etc).

Comment: +0 You did not provide any information as to _where to download_ the .ttf file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add Lucida Grande to the `font-family` tag like this

```
element {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

and hope that the user has Lucida Grande installed or read this from W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-family0 - here they explain how to embed a font (with CSS3)