# Lucida grande font isn't light enough

Tags: css, browser, fonts, photoshop

I have designed a template in wordpress and now I'm writing it in css/html but it seems the browser isn't using my font.

Photoshop:

[image: Photoshop screenshot]

Browser:

[image]

This is my css

```
h1 { font-size: 34px; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 100; }
```

The font in photoshop is Lucida Grande regular.

Comment: I bet you didn't include the font's web font script & directly using the font in your computer. Try to find the web font version.

Comment: Font rendering in browsers and Photoshop are extremely different. You'll never get exactly the same result in all browsers as in Photoshop. Welcome to reality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using Lucida Grande in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375353/using-lucida-grande-in-windows)

Comment: Welcome to the world of web design. Most fonts are replicated in browsers in a different way entirely, you can check out some places such as font squirrel or myfonts.com to see if they have the necessary web versions, but you're more than likely going to be paying for them.

Answer (score 1):

Never use platform-specific fonts ( Mac-only / Windows-only fonts ) in website; it's quite different in representation between browser & the operating system itself. If a visitor of your website does not have the font, it will fallback to next font specified in your `font-family` font stack.

It's suggested to use web fonts in website. You can find similar font in [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts) as alternative.

Yet, the above does not apply to most of the non-Unicode languages, especially CJK (Chinese, Japanese and Korean. Take Chinese as example, since Chinese has a wide range of characters, it is not feasible to make a web font for Chinese, as the file size of the font will be very large. (there are some Chinese web fonts, but most of them are >10MB; no visitors have patience to wait a font to load for a minute before they can read a pretty font)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all answers. 
I fixed it using the "Lucida Sans Unicode" font and the "letter-spacing" css property.

For everyone that have my same problem, here's my solution.

```
h1 { font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif; font-size: 34.14px; text-align: center; font-weight: 100; letter-spacing: 0.6px; }
```